# How to move multiple rows values to one cell using a formula in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am not so handy with the excel formulas. I want to move multiple rows values which is starting after the cell value Related applications and ended before Related parts. Actually, these values are part of Related applications only however showing up in the same column. Here, I want to move these rows values to the next column just in front of the Related applications cell and this formula/condition needs to be applied throughout the sheet because the sheet contains multiple related applications cells and their values in the same column. Please refer the screenshot. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Considering the version of Excel you appear to be using `=CONCATENATE(A2,",",A3,",",A4,",",A5)`

Comment: Okay but I need a condition here where it should stop concatenating when found Related parts in the next cell. It should concatenate only values before related parts cell. This should be applied throughout the column.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in B1 and then drag down:

```
=IF(A1="Related App",TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,OFFSET(A2,0,0,MATCH("Related Part",A1:A100,0)-2,1)),"")
```

Explanation:

**(1)** MATCH("Related Part",A1:A100,0) -> search how far is next "Related Part"

**(2)** OFFSET(A2,0,0, **(1)** -2,1))  -> select the strings to put togheter

**(3)**  IF(A1="Related App",**(2)**,"") -> only do this when near "Related App"